# Ruby Rounding Convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rounding

I'm trying to define a function that respects the following rounding conditions (round to the closest integer or tenth):

[image]

The main issue I found out, was around rounding negative numbers.

Here is my implementation (sorry for the conditional check but its just for this example):

```
  def convention_round(number, to_int = false)
    if to_int
      number.round
    else
      number.round(1)
    end
  end

  convention_round(1.2234) # 1.2
  convention_round(1.2234, true) # 1

  convention_round(1.896) # 1.9
  convention_round(1.896, true) # 2

  convention_round(1.5) # 1.5
  convention_round(1.5, true) # 2

  convention_round(1.55) # 1.6
  convention_round(1.55, true) # 2

  convention_round(-1.2234) # -1.2
  convention_round(-1.2234, true) # -1

  convention_round(-1.896) # -1.9
  convention_round(-1.2234, true) # -2

  convention_round(-1.5) # -1.5
  convention_round(-1.5, true) # -2 (Here I want rounded to -1)

  convention_round(-1.55) # -1.6 (Here I want rounded to -1.5)
  convention_round(-1.55, true) # -2
```

I'm not 100% sure what is the best approach for rounding the negative numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: If `1.5` rounds to `2` and `1.55` rounds to `1.6`, then you are rounding halfway values *up*. But if `-1.5` rounds to `-1` and `-1.55` rounds to `-1.5` then you are rounding halfway values *down*. Is this really intentional? I will provide a solution to this request, but that's a non-standard way of rounding.

Comment: @TomLord Actually I think they're always rounded up, in an absolute sense. Positive are rounding away from zero, negative are rounding toward zero.

Comment: @Matt Yes, I can see that. but that's not how conventional rounding works. It's ironic that the method name is "conventional round", when this is not the convention.

Comment: @TomLord haha, very true. An interesting question precisely because it's unconventional.

Comment: OP I'd be curious to know the use case for the method you need.... is this a school assignment?

Comment: @Matt, it is a very confidential task at work. Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: @RaresR I hope it's not for financial data, otherwise you might get in legal trouble ;)

Comment: @Matt, It is for a sport game. Can you detail a bit why you think it is a weird way of rounding.

Comment: @TomLord can 'but that's not how conventional rounding works', what is the convention for rounding up the numbers from this example? I'm really trying to understand all possibilities.

Comment: If you're curious about "conventional" rounding, you should look at the [IEEE-754 rounding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules). Anything to do with floating point should be covered by the IEEE standards and anything not covered by IEEE standards could be called non-conventional.

Comment: @RaresR You're rounding using two explicit conventions depending on whether the number is positive or negative. The very fact that you hit this problem using *actual conventional rounding* should really highlight the irony. 

But it's really only a note on your method name. You've used `convention` for something quite unconventional. It's not a real problem, just a bit humourous really! it's also exactly the kind of "odd challenge" a programming tutor might set - hence why I wondered if that was the case. "because of sports rules" is also a very sensible explanation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs, you can use [`Integer#round`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-round) (and [`Float#round`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-round)) for this, as follows:

```
def convention_round(number, precision = 0)
  number.round(
    precision,
    half: (number.positive? ? :up : :down)
  )
end

convention_round(1.4)      #=> 1
convention_round(1.5)      #=> 2
convention_round(1.55)     #=> 2
convention_round(1.54, 1)  #=> 1.5
convention_round(1.55, 1)  #=> 1.6

convention_round(-1.4)      #=> -1
convention_round(-1.5)      #=> -1 # !!!
convention_round(-1.55)     #=> -2
convention_round(-1.54, 1)  #=> -1.55
convention_round(-1.55, 1)  #=> -1.5 # !!!
```

This isn't quite the method signature you asked for, but it's a more generic form - since you can supply an arbitrary precision.

However, I would like to point out the irony that (despite the method name) this is **not** a conventional way of rounding numbers.

There are a few different conventions, all(?) of which are supported by the ruby core library (see above link to docs), but this is not one of them.

Comment: For example, take a look at the [PHP implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php). You can see that it also provides the same options as ruby (half-up, half-down, half-even and half-odd), but there is no convention for "positive half-up, negative half-down". There's nothing inherently **wrong** with doing this, I just find it misleading to describe it as "conventional".

Comment: My guess is someone is trying to loot someone's crypto currencies? lol

Comment: The rounding mode the OP is requesting might not be conventional, but it's not completely unknown, either. JavaScript's `Math.round` uses exactly this convention: [ties round towards positive infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round#Description).